# FFMPEG Use image demuxer on audio file with embedded cover image

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, images, mp3

I have an mp3 file with embedded cover art. I would like to generate a video of the image with the audio playing, for the duration of the audio.

I can achieve this with the image in a separate file using :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i "image.jpg" -i "audio.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest -r 1 "output.mp4"
```

Is it possible to do this without separating the image into its own file?

If I run `ffprobe -i audio.mp3` it shows that

```
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x1200 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
Metadata:
  title           : front cover
  comment         : Cover (front)
```

And this is ffprobe of the image: `ffprobe -i image.jpg`

```
Input #0, image2, from 'folder.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53163 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x1200 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
```

From my understanding, the `-loop` and `framerate` options are part of the image demuxer.

Is this possible to do? If not on CLI, would it be doable to modify the source code to do this in <37 years?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the loop filter works:

```
ffmpeg -i "first.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:-1[vid];[vid]loop=loop=-1:size=1:start=0[vid2]" -map [vid2]:v -map 0:a -b:a 320k -shortest -r 1 -movflags +faststart "output.mp4"
```

It is pretty slow though, at only 5x the speed. I will keep fiddling with it to see if I can find a way that works faster.

Comment: It is 3 times faster to generate the video with a static image instead of doing it this way. I think I will just implement a way to extract embedded cover art and save it to a file before running ffmpeg.